# Creating reusable template in xslt to process some elements which are occuring multiple times

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to write a template to process some section and reuse it.

In the below XML, we see Message is repeated in every ,,. I want to write a template to process  and call it when ever needed.

```
        <Data>

           <A>
              <text>this is text</text>
              <Message>
                <local>Local  link</local>
                <STD>External link</STD>
                </Message>
            </A>
            <B>
               <info>Information</info>
               <Message>
                <local>Local uri link</local>
                <STD>External link uri</STD>

                </Message>
            </B>
            <C>
               <longtext>Long Text</longtext>
               <Message>
                <local>Local uri link</local>
                <STD>External link uri</STD>

                </Message>
                </C>
        <Data>
```

Output needed:

```
    <Information>     
          <AA>
                this is text
                <MSG local value="Local uri link" STD value="External link"/>
            </AA>

            <BB>
                Information
                <MSG local value  ="Local uri link"  STD value="External link"/>

            </BB>
            <CC>
                Long Text
                <MSG local value="Local uri link" STD value="External link"/>
            </CC>

    <Information>
```

While processing  tag in every node, I am writing code for every tags in A, B, C.

Sample code written

```
    <Information>

        <xsl:template match="A">
        <AA>
            <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
            <xsl:element name="MSG">
                <xsl:attribute name="local value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Message/local"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="STD value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Message/STD"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
        </AA>
    </Information>
```

similarly for every template I am explicitly writing the code for the block MSG.

Now I want to write a separate template to process . And I want to call this template from every template.

Basically I want to reuse the code written to process

Can any one help me how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
  <Information>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Information>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/A/text | Data/B/info | Data/C/longtext">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Message">
  <MSG local-value="{local}" STD-value="{STD}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input

```
<Data>

   <A>
      <text>this is text</text>
      <Message>
        <local>Local  link</local>
        <STD>External link</STD>
        </Message>
    </A>
    <B>
       <info>Information</info>
       <Message>
        <local>Local uri link</local>
        <STD>External link uri</STD>

        </Message>
    </B>
    <C>
       <longtext>Long Text</longtext>
       <Message>
        <local>Local uri link</local>
        <STD>External link uri</STD>

        </Message>
        </C>
</Data>
```

Saxon 6.5.5 outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Information>

           <AA>
              this is text
              <MSG local-value="Local  link" STD-value="External link"/>
            </AA>
            <BB>
               Information
               <MSG local-value="Local uri link" STD-value="External link uri"/>
            </BB>
            <CC>
               Long Text
               <MSG local-value="Local uri link" STD-value="External link uri"/>
                </CC>
        </Information>
```

Neither your posted input sample nor the wanted output sample are well-formed XML so I had to make some changes to element or attribute names to process as well as to output XML.

Comment: Thank you for the information shared. Is there any chance to write a template to process Message tag separately and call it when ever needed, by passing the text.

Comment: just by <call-template> like that. while passing the parameter i need to pass entire xml tree under Message tag

Comment: @User222 it's not at all clear what you want, what requirement does Martin's solution not meet?

Comment: (Part of) The power of XSLT in my view is `apply-templates` and template matching, not using `call-template` and parameters when the job can be done nicely without them. So while there might be a way to write a named template taking parameters and to call it with `call-template`, I don't see any reason to take that rather cumbersome approach.

Comment: I want to send the data in Message tag as it is to some other template. This answer produces the required output. Indeed, I also want to know if we can pass the entire data in Message tag to some other template.Can you explain if it is possible.

Comment: Well if you write an `xsl:template match="Message"` and then do `<xsl:apply-templates select="Message"/>` or a more general `<xsl:apply-templates/>` then you have the proper and elegant XSLT way of pushing the `Message` elements to the reusable template you have written. There is no need to use parameters or call named templates, if you want to process nodes then write templates matching them and make sure you apply-templates as needed.

Comment: @User222: It *is* possible to use `<xsl:call-template .../>`, but a better practice is *not* to use a named template at all. With his answer, Martin Honnen is showing to you a solution that is in the true spirit of XSLT and that has a number of significant advantages over using a named template. Please, grab the chance to learn something useful -- otherwise why use XSLT at all -- good o'le Assembler is the ultimate solution. +1.